# Bitnami Redmine に Easy Gantt プラグインを入れると Your application is not available となる

Tags: redmine

はじめまして。
もしお分かりの方がいらっしゃいましらアドバイスいただけますでしょうか。

**【したいこと】**
Bitnami Redmine に Easy Gantt(free)プラグインをいれたい

**【問題】**
プラグインを入れてアプリケーションを起動させると「Your application is not available」と表示される

**【環境,インストールバージョン等】**
Windows 10 64bit
Bitnami Redmine Stack 3.3.1-0
  - Redmine 3.3.1
  - Apache 2.4.23
  - ImageMagick 6.7.5
  - MySQL 5.6.33
  - Subversion 1.9.4
  - Git 2.7.4
  - Ruby 2.1.10
  - Rails 4.2.5.1
  - RubyGems 1.8.12
Easy Gantt(free) 2016/12/9にダウンロードしたもの

**【知識レベル】**
先日Redmineを触り始めたところ
Ruby、mySQLの知識ゼロ

**【作業内容】**
1. Bitnamiのサイトから「bitnami-redmine-3.3.1-0-windows-installer.exe」をダウンロードして「C:\Bitnami\redmine」フォルダにインストール
2. アプリケーションを起動し、ログイン→管理→設定→RESTによるWebサービスを有効にするにチェック
3. [https://www.easyredmine.com/redmine-gantt-pluginから](https://www.easyredmine.com/redmine-gantt-plugin%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89)「EasyGanttFree.zip」をダウンロードして解凍後の「easy-gantt」フォルダを「C:\Bitnami\redmine\apps\redmine\htdocs\plugins」フォルダに格納
<以下、EasyGantt公式サイトのインストール手順どおりにコマンドを実行>
https://www.easyredmine.com/redmine-gantt-plugin
4. Bitnami Redmine Stackのコマンド画面を開き、以下コマンドを入力して実行

```
C:\Bitnami\redmine\apps\redmine\htdocs>bundle install You are trying
to install in deployment mode after changing your Gemfile. Run `bundle
install` elsewhere and add the updated Gemfile.lock to version
control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze by running
`bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* redmine_extensions

C:\Bitnami\redmine\apps\redmine\htdocs>bundle exec rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RedmineExtensions
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/lib/easy_gantt/redmine_patch/helpers/application_helper_patch.rb:26:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/after_init.rb:8:in
`block in <top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/after_init.rb:7:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/after_init.rb:7:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/init.rb:22:in
`require_relative'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/init.rb:22:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:155:in
`block in load'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in
`load'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:21:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in
`block in load_config_initializer'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in
`instrument'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in
`load_config_initializer'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in
`block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in
`block in <class:Engine>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
`instance_exec'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
`run'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
`block in run_initializers'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
`tsort_each_child'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
`run_initializers'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in
`initialize!'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/environment.rb:14:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in
`require_environment!'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in
`block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in
`<top (required)>' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment (See full
trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Bitnami\redmine\apps\redmine\htdocs>bundle exec rake
redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production DL is deprecated, please
use Fiddle rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant
RedmineExtensions
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/lib/easy_gantt/redmine_patch/helpers/application_helper_patch.rb:26:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/after_init.rb:8:in
`block in <top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/after_init.rb:7:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/after_init.rb:7:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/init.rb:22:in
`require_relative'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/init.rb:22:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:155:in
`block in load'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in
`load'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:21:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in
`block in load_config_initializer'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in
`instrument'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in
`load_config_initializer'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in
`block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in
`block in <class:Engine>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
`instance_exec'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
`run'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
`block in run_initializers'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
`each'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
`tsort_each_child'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
`run_initializers'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in
`initialize!'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/environment.rb:14:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in
`require_environment!'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in
`block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/Bitnami/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in
`<top (required)>' Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate =>
environment (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

5.Manager Tool の Manage Servers で Reset All　→　Thin_redmineとThin_redmine2がStoppedになり、アプリケーションを起動しても「Your application is not available」となる

Answer (score 2):

私も同じ内容でハマっていましたが、以下の手順で使えるようになりました。
（私が試したのはRedmine3.2なので、もしかしたら違うところがあるかもしれません。）

1. `.\apps\redmine\htdocs\plugins\` にダウンロードした `easy_gantt` フォルダを置く
2. `bundle install` を実行。
   （もし `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory` となったら、 `.bundle` フォルダを持つ場所まで移動する。おそらく `cd ./apps/redmine/htdocs` ）
   ここで `redmine_extensions` の名前が出てきますが、 `gem list` でgemの一覧を見ても `redmine_extensions` が存在していないはず。
3. `bundle install --no-deployment` を実施すると、 `Could not verify the SSL certificate for ～` とエラーが出るはず。
   （`gem install redmine_extensions` で `redmine_extensions` をインストールしようとすると
   `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 ～` と言われる。）
   SSL証明書の認証に失敗してgemファイルのインストール元が見れない様子。
4. SSL証明書の認証に失敗している様子なので、以下のHPを参考にrubygemを更新する
   http://qiita.com/betrue12/items/059c2424f27fd31969f9
   http://swiftfe0.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/10/13/194701
   （実施後 `gem -v` でgemのバージョンを確認すると2.2.X→2.6.8とかにあがるはず。）
5. 念のため `gem update --system` でRubyGemを最新版に更新する。
   一応 `gem update bundler` も実施
6. もう一回 `bundle install` 今度は普通に通るはず
   （ `bundle install --no-deployment` じゃないとだめかもしれません。。。）
   実施後に `gem list` でgemの一覧にて `redmine_extensions` が存在していればOK。
7. `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` でDB修正
8. `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` でプラグインを登録

こちらでどうでしょう。

Comment: [kuroさん](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/20184/kuro)より「質問者ではありませんが、ありがとうございます。同じ内容で躓いて、プラグインインストールできました」との報告がありました。（回答として寄せられたので転記いたします）